# How can I improve visits and visibility to my stock photography, particularly on Fotolia?

Tags: web, stock-photography

I've had [photos posted on Fotolia](http://us.fotolia.com/p/201037170) for months now and have had very few visits to the pictures.  What can I do to improve the visibility and/or appeal of my stock photos, particularly on Fotolia?  Are there any special methods to increase visibility for photos that have posted recently?

Comment: This is getting off topic votes (and is almost about to close) and I'm not quite sure why.  Its a question about improving hits at a stock photography site.  Given all the other tangential questions we answer - it feels like a question about the business of stock photography to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keywords are not so bad. Only "Sexy girl" lacks a little.
Maybe try to move the order, firsts are most important. You may do this in your control panel. And submit more images.

"Latest Uploads" are linked in page footer.